# Select a checkbox by default

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that this question has been asked before, but I am struggling with selecting a default checkbox. I want the checkbox to be "Kenyan Used" by default as in the picture below:[Selected "Kenyan Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxJYq.png). What i have tried is `$taxonomy= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_id FROM par_taxonomy WHERE (taxonomy = 'condition' AND term_taxonomy_id= '181')");`. Though I don't how the below code implements this, I know it is a for loop, but how do i modify it to work for my case?. Below is the specific code from where the taxonomies are fetched from:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($modern_filter)){ $counter = 0;
    foreach ($modern_filter as $modern_filter_unit) {
        $counter++;
        $terms = get_terms(array($modern_filter_unit['slug']), $args);
        if (empty($modern_filter_unit['slider']) && $modern_filter_unit['slug'] != 'price') { /*<!--If its not price-->*/
                     //if ($modern_filter_unit['slug'] != 'price') { /* != 'price'<!--If its not price-->*/
            /*First one if ts not image goes on another view*/
            if ($counter == 1 and empty($modern_filter_unit['use_on_car_modern_filter_view_images'])
                    and !$modern_filter_unit['use_on_car_modern_filter_view_images']) {
                if (!empty($terms)) { ?>
<div class="stm-accordion-single-unit <?php echo esc_attr($modern_filter_unit['slug']); ?>">
   <a class="title" data-toggle="collapse"
      href="#<?php echo esc_attr($modern_filter_unit['slug']) ?>" aria-expanded="true">
      <h5><?php esc_html_e($modern_filter_unit['single_name'], 'motors'); ?></h5>
      <span class="minus"></span>
   </a>
   <div class="stm-accordion-content">
      <div class="collapse in content" id="<?php echo esc_attr($modern_filter_unit['slug']); ?>">
         <div class="stm-accordion-content-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
            <?php if (!empty($_GET[$modern_filter_unit['slug']]) and $_GET[$modern_filter_unit['slug']] == $term->slug) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               jQuery(window).load(function () {
                var $ = jQuery;
                $('input[name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug . '-' . $term->term_id); ?>"]').click();
                $.uniform.update();
               });
            </script>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="stm-single-unit">
               <label>
               <input type="checkbox"
                  name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug . '-' . $term->term_id); ?>"
                  data-name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>"
                  />
               <?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>
               </label>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What does your taxonomy query have to do with a checked checkbox, I don't understand?

Comment: @Michael, that is where the condition e.g. Kenyan Used is stored/ selected from.

Comment: Have you looked at [checked](https://codex.wordpress.org/checked)?

Comment: @Michael, yes I did, but the thing is it's looping through all the Conditions how do i check that specific condition

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the checkbox you want to do this for: Add an if statement to determine if the checkbox should be checked by default

```
 <input type="checkbox"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug . '-' . $term->term_id); ?>"
        data-name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>"
        <?php if($condition){?> checked <?php } ?>
 />
```

Replace $condition with something to determine if this is the checkbox you want checked by default. If you want all checkbox checked by default just add 'checked' inside the input tag without any if statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Eleonora Ivanova, the checkbox selects by default now, but the issue is its not loading the checked condition.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about this or show me what you have?

Comment: sure okay so see when you load https://muddywatersltd.com/pickaride/kenyan-used/, it is supposed to only show condition of "Kenyan Used", but with the code you provided i have to uncheck then check it back so that it can filter the condition

Comment: Right okay, that it a separate issue. That's related to the javascript that is actually filtering your posts, looks like its either running on change, so wouldn't do anything on load or something similar to that. If you pin point in your js code where this is done you should be able to fix this.

Comment: Thanks @Eleonora, but I dont think i know where the JS is :( maybe "   <script type="text/javascript">
               jQuery(window).load(function () {
                var $ = jQuery;
                $('input[name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug . '-' . $term->term_id); ?>"]').click();
                $.uniform.update();
               });
            </script>" I am not sure

Comment: Ok, are you using a library or a plugin for this? There should be documentation for it somewhere? There might even be an option for this so you won't have to amend your php as required earlier.

Comment: it's called motors theme, but the problem is the devs said there is not option like this at the moment from their side.

Comment: Ok, the guidance I can give you is pinpoint the event that causes the change using the inspector in your browser you would probably be on change, see what it does and then add the similar functionality on document ready.

Comment: i got the javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `checked` attribute to your checkbox. You can check for the required term with an `if` statement. You need to add the following:

```
<?php if ($term->name == 'Kenyan Used') { echo ' checked'; } ?>
```

So then your input code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"
      name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug . '-' . $term->term_id); ?>"
      data-name="<?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>"
      <?php if ($term->name == 'Kenyan Used') { echo ' checked'; } ?> />
<?php echo esc_attr($term->name); ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @mkveksas, the checkbox selects by default now, but the issue is its not loading the checked condition.